# How to classify digits and words in Handwritten Text recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I am working with handwritten text recognition using neural nets, 
thinks i have used in this

- opencv for image processing
- page segmentation and extracting text boxes
- word segmentation ( or any suggestions for better accurate segmentation/mask the text )

i have a form with name, age and date of birth text boxes
the result for the name field is good( able to recognize ) but for the DOB and age it is not able to recognize it completely as digits some of digits like '1' and '0' are recognized as 'i' and 'o'.

how can i classify this into words and digits, or can i use any other models for digits only ( currently i have trained the NN with IAM dataset-words ), or any suggestion.

[image: example pic]

```
result : --i-16-16-
result : -i-i6-86-
```

Answer (score 0):

You could train another NN, since digit recognition is not a relatively computational intense task.

Alternatively, if the document has a fixed format then you are aware where the age and dob is present. In that case while thresholding the output layer to decide the output, only do it for the neurons that represent numbers.

For example, say you have 5 numbers `{'1','2','3','4','5'}` and 5 alphabets `{'a','e','i','o','u'}`. The output layer of your trained NN gives, `[0.38, 0.006, 0.01, 0.004, 0.1, 0.03, 0.009, 0.4, 0.001, 0.06]`.

On which you perform softmax to obtain a probabilistic interpretation. And select one output. Instead perform softmax only on the neurons representing numbers. You can also think of it as prior probability being zero.

Here `i` has a higher activation than `1`. But when performing softmax you only pick the neurons that represent numbers. Hence you get `1`.

Comment: Yes i have fixed formate where dob and age text boxes comes. Do i need to use anothe model for digit recognition

Comment: No it is not necessary. As I have explained from the output layer pick only the activations of the neurons that represent numbers.

Comment: what if i have image which has both numbers and letters like 'i23h'

Comment: Then you can use your initial model, can you not? If you are asking how to differentiate the 'o' from '0', you can use more data to train. But even with a good model it might still give wrong results, it is difficult even for humans to differentiate, after all both are just small circles. If you have some context like dob, then you know it is a '0'. You could use that to make your decision as well.